# What does this function do when it has code inside it with ':'?

Tags: jquery

I know the question is very vague and I apologize in advance. I have these two lines of code someone wrote for me and I just need a short explanation as to what they mean. Thanks in advance. So what is happening inside the function?

```
 var addNumbersToHeadings = $tocPlaceholder.data("add-numbers-to-headings");

function getTocSettings() {
        return {
            addNumbersToHeadings: $tocPlaceholder.data("add-numbers-to-headings"),

        };
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript variables of type object are defined like this:

```
var property = {color: "red"};
```

So your function returns an object with the key "addNumbersToHeadings" and the calculated value.

Comment: I think he has confusion with data attribute functionality.

Comment: @ParthShah No I know that it is returning the value of the data-attribute in the function. Question has been answered thanks.